# jars from intellij idea dont work - no output

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jar

I'm using the latest version of the IntelliJ idea and java dk,re,fx versions. [image]So i go to file->project structure->artifacts->+->jar->from modules with dependencies->select main class Main(everything else default).After that, I go build->artifacts->javafx(name of artifact and project name) and open up explorer to open the jar but I don't get anything as output. I've already tried reinstalling JRE and setting a variable in the windows path.
Project Structure: src->package:sample->class:Main(along with controller cause its a JavaFX app).Also, I get no errors when running the app on the ide, everything works fine. I have a suspicion that it's the VM options that cause trouble (--module-path C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls) because the rest of the libraries are packed in the jar and checked with win rar. Lastly, I have checked the manifest file and it points to the Main class correctly.
Other solutions I have found don't work for me.

Can anyone see what's wrong? thnx for all the help in advance and have a good day!

Edit: the src\sample(package) folder apart from Main.java and Controller.java has some pictures that are used in the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute your JAR in IDE:

In Select Dialog of executed Actifact select `Edit Configurations...`

[image: Edit Configurations]

Inside click on Pus and select `JAR`

[image: Select JAR]

Then provide path to jar file and test it by running from IDE

Comment: thnx i will try it out rn

Comment: So I tried it out when I add --module-path /path/to/JavaFX/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls it runs completely fine when I remove it though it doesn't run saying JavaFX runtime components are missing that are required to run this application.

Comment: please edit your question and make a pictures how you have created the artifact

Comment: btw when i run cmd and do( cd /path/to/jar &&java -jar javafx.jar )it says:Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: sample/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 59.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 Although i have latest jre and jdk versions (1.8.0_281 and 15,0.2/11.0.10 respectively)

Comment: yep knew it! its the module path thing for the vm options when i run cmd and put the "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe" --module-path C:\Users\USER\Downloads\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -jar C:\Users\USER\IdeaProjects\javafx\out\artifacts\javafx_jar3\javafx.jar it runs fine but how will i make this so that it ll run without this

Comment: `You have tried`. Please remove not needed `resources.META-INF`. Use default `src`. Execute a JAR without some VM Options and provide in your Question the **error** Message you receive

Comment: i resolved the issue by executing in cmd:"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe" --module-path C:\Users\USER\Downloads\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -jar C:\Users\USER\IdeaProjects\javafx\out\artifacts\javafx_jar3\javafx.jar

Comment: I also fixed the jni problem(problem  i had with system variables) so its all good now thanks a lot for the help and time.Have a good one!

Comment: great, then you can set the answer as accepted, to show, that problem is solved.

Comment: im sorry im new to stack overflow would you mind sharing with me the way to mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: nevermind found it thnx again for your time and have a good day